# Wordpress CSS Frontpage not working properly

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

So I have xampp and currently trying to learn some Wordpress development. I've made a simple bootstrap page into Wordpress, but which ever page I put as my front page does not load any CSS, whilst the other pages work fine.

If I change the front page to a page that previously worked fine, it also loses the CSS.

https://i.gyazo.com/bcb75b7a7fa64cd99cb43bd1c3067324.png
https://i.gyazo.com/7184fec113c09755961088fa69191528.png

What am I doing wrong here? I am running everything locally on 127.0.0.1

Thanks in advance for helping me !

Comment: Are you actually loading the css files for the frontend?...

Comment: Where did you load your css files?

Comment: How do I check that? Sorry this is my first time working with Wordpress

Comment: The same as any other website, in the `<head>`

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/e158a98e0ea4b0f2dc895cb9fea25267.png

Comment: Your file structure isn't any help really, you just need to check you're loading the files in

Comment: Check your header.php

Comment: http://pastebin.com/FPbXLg6X

Comment: The proper way for wordpress to load style is to use wp_enqueue_style() in functions.php

Comment: `  <link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url');?>" rel="stylesheet">` check what that line evaluates to and that is your css file's location

Comment: http://pastebin.com/MGLn8F9v

Comment: Doing what Velimir said just rekt both my pages

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to add css in your files using WordPress to use the function `wp_enqueue_style` it will not override the css declaration but enqueue it

In your functions.php

```
function your_scripts() {
 wp_enqueue_style( 'filjoseph-style', get_stylesheet_uri());
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_scripts' );
```

and putting this `<?php wp_head(); ?>`in your `header.php` before `</head>`  in your head section, wordpress will ensure the style.css loaded properly.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/MGLn8F9v - I already have that? But my problem seems to be with the header file, in particular:

Comment: <link href="<?php bloginfo('style.css');?>" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Yes you can do that, but more proper if wp_enqueue_style.Read it here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

Comment: I've tried and I can't get it to work no matter what I do. :(